# Salesforce for Outlook plug-in add new event button not working

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

having issue with my Saleforce for Outlook plug-in

running plug-in version 3.4.1.25
Outlook version is 2013

There is a + plus sign on plug-in side bar that opens a new event for some users but for a few others it does nothing.
[image]

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall but this did not fix
Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the version?? Winter??

Comment: Winter 18' @Edu Trujillo

Answer (score 0):

This issue was eventually corrected by my company’s Security / Network team – it turned out to be a proxy/ firewall issue and it took some time for the Security team to figure out how to allow the plug-in to pass through.

We were trying to follow the recommended IE Optimal settings for running Salesforce in the Internet Explorer Browser and while doing that I found that on IE – Tools – Internet Options – Connection tab – LAN Setting, we had an address listed in the “Use Automatic configuration script” checkbox setting.  Security team explained that is a proxy we used for security - this what needed to be adjusted to allow the plug-in to work.  I don’t know what all the Security team did to the proxy but eventually they found the correct setting and it is now working.